# find all the divisors of $6$ and $4+2\sqrt{5}$,then find $\gcd(6,4+2\sqrt{5})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

By inspection we see that the divisors of $6$ are  $1,2,3,6$

For $4+2\sqrt{5}$ we have $4+2\sqrt{5}=2(2+\sqrt{5})$

showing that  $\gcd(6,4+2\sqrt{5})=2$

Is this method correct; if not, how can I do this successfully?

Comment: It seems right.

Comment: could there be a complex number like $1+i$ or a rational number of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$ that divides this two,this question was worth 17 points in my number theory exam,i wonder if this is all to be done

Comment: @Jonas12 Have you already studied basic number theory of quadratic number fields?  Please give some context.

Comment: yes i have studied quadratic number fields,it is in the context of rational numbers $D$ and  complex numbers $s+t\sqrt{D}$

Comment: only basics,i havent went much further